# Adding conditions to a view template file in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-templates

I need to add a condition to a button hard-coded into the template file in a Drupal 7 theme. I would like the 'compare' button only to appear on the node pages of products that have certain taxonomy terms attached to them. I guess, it could be done with a simple IF, but I'm not a developer and only know the very basics of PHP syntax, so I would be really grateful, if someone could describe in detail how to implement a solution, perhaps even provide a snippet of code that I can customize and paste in the right place!

```
<div class="actions">
    <?php print flag_create_link('wishlist', $node->nid); ?>
    <?php print flag_create_link('compare', $node->nid); ?>
  </div><!-- .actions -->
</div>
```

This is the section in the code of the node--product.tpl.php file that puts out the action buttons. I would like the second one, the compare button to only appear for nodes that have certain taxonomy terms.

Thank you in advance!

Huba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code.

```
<?php
  $display_compare = FALSE; // don't display by default
  $tids = array(1, 2, 3); // array of certain taxonomy terms' tids

  foreach ($node->TERM_FIELD_NAME[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $delta => $term) {
    if (in_array($term['tid'], $tids)) {
      $display_compare = TRUE; // display if node has at least one of specified terms
      break;
    }
  }

  if ($display_compare) {
    print flag_create_link('compare', $node->nid);
  }
?>
```

Please don't forget to replace "TERM_FIELD_NAME" with your field name and "1, 2, 3" with your list of tids.

Comment: Just 1 more short question: I need this same logic for items on my product grid, it has another template file, where the code that displays the button looks like this:

    </span>
    <?php print flag_create_link('wishlist', $fields['nid']->content); ?>
    <?php print flag_create_link('compare', $fields['nid']->content); ?>
      </div><!-- .actions -->

I guess, i have to define, where to draw the taxonomy terms from, so it needs some modification, how should I do that?

Comment: just add this line before code from my answer: $node = node_load($fields['nid']->content);

Comment: Perfect! Thank you again!

Comment: hey! sorry to bother u again, but I have to do almost the same thing again with another view template - compare the value of the sell price of a product displayed in a list view against a fixed value, and print smt if its bigger and someting else if smaller - what syntax do I use to compare the sell price against the fixed value ? :> sorry for the newb questions, I'm gonna take php lessons when I'm done with this site....:p